# How do retrieve information from my API using AFNetworking now that I have my token?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, afnetworking

I have successfully retrieved a token with an Authorization request. I now have credentials that read like so:

```
<AFOAuthCredential accessToken:"someToken" tokenType:"bearer" refreshToken:"someRefreshToken" expiration:"2015-10-21 05:02:22 +0000">
```

I am now trying to use this token to make a GET request to my API. I am using the following to make my request:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kBaseUrl]];
AFOAuthCredential *credential = [AFOAuthCredential retrieveCredentialWithIdentifier:KServiceProviderCredential];
[manager GET:@"/api/users"
  parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
     }];
```

As you can see I haven't actually set my credentials anywhere in this request. Which method would I use for this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this what I was looking for:

```
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", credential.accessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Once I make my request I have to set my token for the 'Authorization' header in order to access my api.

Comment: Aren't you getting 403? I am trying to make the same request but its receiving 403 from the server. I checked and there is no redirection. Did you go through with anything near this?

Comment: 403 means 'Access denied/Forbidden'. Ensure that you have received a token prior to making your API request.